# Security Engineering Potential Threat?

Tags: integrity, confidentiality, availability

I've been working on some security engineering problems and there is no solution provided so if someone can clarify, would be great.

From the point of view of security engineering, which is **not** a potential threat?

1. Users denying that they modified electronic assets in the organization.
2. An earthquake.
3. A person disclosing secrets to third parties, after such person has signed a non-disclosure
   agreement intended to protect these secrets.
4. A person accidentally disconnecting the electricity of a computer server.
5. Users not following proper procedures to update electronic assets in the organization

Now for this question I am getting #1, simply because I wouldn't classify a denial of modified assets a threat, that would just fall in the Integrity portion of security properties.

Can someone clarify that this is indeed #1?

Thank you to everyone.

Comment: The questions are weirdly worded.  I would say that users modifying devices is definitely a risk, but the fact that they are denying it is not a risk, per se.  I'm also not sure what 5 is referring to?

Comment: The old #5 was the result of a mistake while editing.

Comment: If this is from a textbook or course, go back to the definition of "threat" and apply it very literally.  (I agree that #1 is the answer, but you need to satisfy yourself, and maybe your professor, that you can explain *why* it's the right answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Security is so fun!
The correct answer is #1 because it is the only scenario that doesn't have an immediate impact on the security of assets on your organization. #1 doesn't do anything!

2) can compromise the physical security of your building or office, w/e

3) is the direct disclosure of sensitive data, the very definition of an internal security breach

4) can significantly disrupt operations, depending on what the server is used for and may create blacked out periods where you do not know what happened

5) can result in untrusted or outright malicious software installations or introduce additional weaknesses

Comment: Correct - 2-5 actually are a problem. #1 is a side-effect of a threat.